# Why does my buttons not change background if I comment out the Window.CommandBindings?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

So I've been playing around with creating a custom title bar using WPF and this is what I have

```
<!--Add the WindowChrome object-->
    <WindowChrome.WindowChrome>
        <WindowChrome CaptionHeight="34" />
    </WindowChrome.WindowChrome>

    <Window.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            
            <Style x:Key="CaptionButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                            <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent" Width="44" Height="30">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="txt" Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="10" 
                                   Foreground="Black" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   RenderOptions.ClearTypeHint="Auto" TextOptions.TextRenderingMode="Aliased"  TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display"/>
                            </Grid>
                            <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                    <Setter TargetName="LayoutRoot" Property="Background" Value="#E5E5E5"/>
                                    <Setter TargetName="txt" Property="Foreground" Value="#000000"/>
                                </Trigger>
                            </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Style>

            <!--Minimize-->
            <Style x:Key="MinimizeButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource CaptionButtonStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE949;"/>
            </Style>

            <!--Maximize-->
            <Style x:Key="MaximizeButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource CaptionButtonStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE739;"/>
            </Style>

            <!--Restore-->
            <Style x:Key="RestoreButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource CaptionButtonStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE923;"/>
            </Style>

            <!--Close-->
            <Style x:Key="CloseButtonStyle" TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource CaptionButtonStyle}">
                <Setter Property="Content" Value="&#xE106;"/>
            </Style>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Window.Resources>

    <!-- Title bar button commands -->
     <Window.CommandBindings>
         <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed_Close" />
         <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MaximizeWindowCommand}" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed_Maximize" />
         <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand}" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed_Minimize" />
         <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.RestoreWindowCommand}" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed_Restore" />
     </Window.CommandBindings>

    <Border x:Name="MainWindowBorder" BorderBrush="LightCoral" BorderThickness="0" >
        <Grid x:Name="parentContainer" Background="LightBlue">
            
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height ="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height ="*"/> 
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <!--Window chrome-->
            <Grid Grid.Row="0" Height="30" Background="#F999">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <!--App icon-->
                    <Image Source="/Resources/watermelon.ico" Width="18" Margin="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                    <TextBlock Text="Sweet App" FontFamily="Arial" Margin="4 3 0 0" />
                </StackPanel>

                <!--Caption buttons-->
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" >
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource MinimizeButtonStyle}" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" ToolTip="Minimize"
                            Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand}"/>
                    <Button x:Name="RestoreButton" Visibility="Collapsed" Style="{StaticResource RestoreButtonStyle}" 
                            Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.RestoreWindowCommand}" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" ToolTip="Restore"/>
                    <Button x:Name="MaximizeButton" Visibility="Visible" Style="{StaticResource MaximizeButtonStyle}" 
                            Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MaximizeWindowCommand}" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" ToolTip="Maximize" />
                    <Button Style="{StaticResource CloseButtonStyle}" WindowChrome.IsHitTestVisibleInChrome="True" ToolTip="Close"
                            Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </Grid>
            
            <!--App content-->
            <Grid Grid.Row="1" x:Name="AppArea">
                <Path Data="M50,0L100,50 50,100 0,50z" Fill="White" Stretch="Fill" Stroke="Black" StrokeThickness="2" />
            </Grid>

        </Grid>
    </Border>
```

And that works great!
However if I were to comment out this part

```
 <Window.CommandBindings>
     <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.CloseWindowCommand}" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed_Close" />
     <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MaximizeWindowCommand}" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed_Maximize" />
     <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.MinimizeWindowCommand}" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed_Minimize" />
     <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static SystemCommands.RestoreWindowCommand}" CanExecute="CommandBinding_CanExecute" Executed="CommandBinding_Executed_Restore" />
 </Window.CommandBindings>
```

Then when I hover over the buttons (Minimize, Maximize and Close) they don't change color anymore and there are no obvious errors presented to me. And as far as I know, it shouldn't change anything UI related since the actual trigger for changing the button background is already defined above in the `Window.Resources`

Why is this happening?

Here's the code behind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            StateChanged += MainWindowStateChangeRaised;
        }

        // Can execute
        private void CommandBinding_CanExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            e.CanExecute = true;
        }

        // Minimize
        private void CommandBinding_Executed_Minimize(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SystemCommands.MinimizeWindow(this);
        }

        // Maximize
        private void CommandBinding_Executed_Maximize(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SystemCommands.MaximizeWindow(this);
        }

        // Restore
        private void CommandBinding_Executed_Restore(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SystemCommands.RestoreWindow(this);
        }

        // Close
        private void CommandBinding_Executed_Close(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            SystemCommands.CloseWindow(this);
        }

        // State change
        private void MainWindowStateChangeRaised(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
            {
                MainWindowBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(8);
                RestoreButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
                MaximizeButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else
            {
                MainWindowBorder.BorderThickness = new Thickness(0);
                RestoreButton.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
                MaximizeButton.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: When Command is set, `IsEnabled` will be synched with CanExecute. `IsEnabled` will not be true unless the Command is properly provided and CanExecute is true.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean! Super interesting!